# Develop for android with Visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio

I just got an android phone and now I want to make an application for it in Visual studio. Is this possible?

I found a topic about it earlier but that topic was from 2010 might be that it's possible now?

Comment: I doubt it. A lot of VS people use ReSharper, because VS lacks some essential stuff. Go see what authors of ReSharper produce as their main product. And yes it works wiht Android. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 1):

Native android applications are written in java and associated textual files.  Visual studio is certainly capable of editing these, and with some setup work launching the appropriate build tools or an ant script.  But it's probably not particularly well suited to such work.

As other have mentioned, there are some alternative development languages/paths that may be a more natural fit for visual studio, but are a less natural fit (less native and/or less supported) for running on the android device - though the results may be sufficient for a given purpose.

Comment: "Native android applications are written in Java" -> Technically native coding on Android is done in C/C++ or assembler, using the NDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: "Native" is a context-dependent word.  In comparison to alternatives not supported by the android system itself such as .NET, or javascript in the browser, a Dalvik app is "native".  But yes, in comparison to code running under Dalvik, jni C code is "native".  Note that the later would fall under "associated textual files"

Answer (score 0):

If you develop HTML5 and then use PhoneGap, it should be possible. There is also a mono port (.NET) to Android you can use to develop in .NET and then port over.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this:

[Mono for android](http://android.xamarin.com/)

Not sure it is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with C/C++, you can develop for Android with Visual Studio 2010. Using vs-android:
http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/